# post list of device id in a group

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

The design of my api is

```
{
    "id": "667c476ca953483493afa265e5d500b0",
    "name": "Home"
}
```

This is the result of GET API. In posting, i want the list of devices to be posted. For example, if user want to post devices to Home group, then the url i have designed is /group/group_token/add(/group/667c476ca953483493afa265e5d500b0/add). The data sending format is

```
{
"devices":[<device_id1>, <device_id2>]
}

i.e

{
"devices":"[5ac41ba7e6ae4628982b2c81c99343a8], [7nu21ba7e6ae4628982b2c81c99343a8]"
}
```

Here is my model, serializer and APIView i have done so far

```
class BaseDevice(PolymorphicModel):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=250, blank=False, null=False)
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User, blank=False, null=False)
    token = models.UUIDField(default=uuid.uuid4, unique=True, editable=False)
    group = models.ForeignKey('DeviceGroup', related_name="groups", null=True, blank=True)

class Device(BaseDevice):
    description = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)

class DeviceGroup(models.Model):
    token = models.UUIDField(default=uuid.uuid4, unique=True, editable=False)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=250, blank=False, null=False)
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User, blank=False, null=False)


class DeviceGroupSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    id = serializers.UUIDField(source='token', format='hex', read_only=True)
    class Meta:
        model = DeviceGroup
        fields = ['id','name']


class DevicesGroupsAPIView(APIView):
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticated,)
    def get_serializer_class(self):
        if self.request.user.is_staff:
            return DeviceGroupSerializer

    def get_object(self, user, token):
        try:
            return BaseDevice.objects.filter(owner=user).get(token=token)
        except ObjectDoesNotExist:
            return error.RequestedResourceNotFound().as_response()

    def get(self, request, format=None):
        reply = {}
        try:
            groups = DeviceGroup.objects.filter(owner=request.user)
            reply['data'] = DeviceGroupSerializer(groups, many=True).data
        except:
            reply['data'] = []
        return Response(reply, status.HTTP_200_OK)

    def post(self, request, token=None, format=None):
        device_group_instance = DeviceGroup.objects.get(token=token)
        for device_token in request.data['devices']:
            device = Device.objects.get(token=device_token, owner=request.user)
            device.group = device_group_instance
            device.save()
```

How can i do the posting? I get an error on token part. It says

> DeviceGroup matching query does not exist.

How should my posting be?

UPDATE

Frist screenshot
The url is device_group/ . When i try to post from there. i get above error not matching query one

[image]

Second Screenshot

The url is in the screenshot browser. I dont get device list to post rather i see name field.

[image]

Comment: Somehow, you have to deliver a valid token through your `post()` function (or retrieve it from within the function).

Comment: Sorry i did not understand you. Can you show me an example, please?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how this is supposed to work, but for whatever reason your `post()` function is not obtaining a valid `token` that matches an existing `DeviceGroup`.

Make sure that `DeviceGroup` is the model you are intending to call.

If you are manually instantiating `post()` somewhere else, check to see that a valid `token` is being passed to it.

Otherwise you will need to retrieve it in the function itself. For example, if the token is stored in a [session variable](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/http/sessions/#examples), you can do:

```
def post(self, request, token=None, format=None):

    token = request.session.token

    device_group_instance = DeviceGroup.objects.get(token=token)
    for device_token in request.data['devices']:
        device = Device.objects.get(token=device_token, owner=request.user)
        device.group = device_group_instance
        device.save()
```

Comment: when i load the url /group/group_token/add in the browser, i see the group of that specific token and the Name field for posting. But for posting i need to send list of device id not the name.